# Class that has the member Vector of its own members

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, smart-pointers

I'm trying to write a Neural Network. I've done it before in other languages, and using matrices libraries; however, I wanted to make it on my own, to better understand them. However I have run into a problem with my classes.

I am doing this in C++.

I have a class called ANN. It has a vector of layers.
layers are a class called Node.
However, within node I want to access the previous layer of nodes, so I can calculate this node's values.

I know if I have a class, and I want one of its members to be of itself it has to be a pointer.
ex.

```
class Node{
public:
    // Public methods/members here
private:
    Node *previousNode;
}
```

However, this is not what I want.
I want `*previousNode` to be ancestor of nodes

here is an example of what I want

```
class Node{
public:
    //Public functions/members here
private:
    vector <Node*> previousLayer;
}
```

Now I've heard in this situation it would be better to use a smart pointer. I don't exactly know what that is, I know it is basically a wrapper for pointers that manage them. I also thought the main reason smart pointers were used is because some pointers get left NULL or not deleted after use, but I did not think that would really matter seeing as the scope of this class could only possible end when the program ends.

My question is how would I implement a vector of pointers to the class the vector is in.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, it sounds like you want each instance of `Node` to contain a list of pointers to other `Node` objects that it is connected to.

What you have written is fine, but as you say, it could make for safer code to use `std::shared_ptr`.

```
class Node{
 public:
     //Public functions/members here
 private:
     vector <shared_ptr<Node>> previousLayer;
 }
```

You should allocate your nodes with `std::make_shared` and they will persist in memory for as long as they are used (no need for `new` or `delete`.)

Comment: No shared ownership is used here, better use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot several nodes in the current layer will point to the same node in the previous layer, so unique ownership isn't the way to go here.  Perhaps a better approach is to have the nodes owned elsewhere, and have the network structure be vectors of observer pointers.

Comment: Thanks, shared ownership would be used here as @M.M stated, sorry if the purpose of each node was unclear, however I am still wondering how I will access these. I understand how to access items in a vector but will I still have to dereference the pointer or anything special for a smart pointer?

Comment: @MilesSmith you can use `->` and `*` similar to a raw pointer

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector <Node*> previousLayer;
```

if you want to handle all the element in the vector, using the iterator:

```
for (auto it = previousLayer.begin(); it != previousLayer.end(); ++it)
{
    Node* node = *it;
    handle(node);
}

// Note: you can using "for (std::vector<Node*>::iterator it = previousLayer.begin(); it != previousLayer.end(); ++it)" instead.
```

if you only want to access one element, using the operator []:

```
Node* node = previousLayer[n];
handle(node);
// but be careful, don't make the n out of range. that means n must be "0 <= n < previousLayer.size()"
```

vector introduction: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector